# Where Magento check to show products for each store?

Tags: multistore, overrides

As you know, Magento supports multi-stores. I'm working with an extension that need to link a store with a specific warehouse.

For example, a store which sales furniture will be linked with a warehouse for furniture, a clothes store will be linked with a warehouse for clothes.

So I have a question, where Magento check to show products for each store? I need to rewrite this function.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

When I read about "explanation of Magento's Store / Store View / Website layers", I saw that "Products and Categories are managed on the store level".

So where exactly the code that "manage" products and categories?

Comment: Magento is a module based system so the module controlling catalog/products is the Catalog module, you can find everything you want to know/read about magento catalog implementation you can find it in /app/code/mage/catalog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can get product collection per store by using the following command:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
     ->setStoreId($storeId)
     ->getCollection();
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know where exactly in Mage Core this code is used. I want to read their implementation.

Comment: Class: `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tree` Method:  `getCategoryCollection()`

Comment: Thanks. Is this the same file that will return different product collection when I choose different store view?